# How to image a windows machine and put it on a Mac?

Tags: windows-7, macos, mac, macbook, boot-camp

I have a desktop running windows 7 Professional, which I invested countless number of hours to setup various development environments and tools.

I just purchased a MacBook Pro and need to replicate the same environment.
Previously I was using bootcamp to dualboot windows or Mac OS and had to re-install all the tools and programs on Windows running on my Mac.

Other than moving the HardDrive on my PC to a sled with firewire and boot from the portable HD. Is there an easier way to replicate my existing Windows Machine and place it on my MacBook Pro?

Has anyone used the built in Windows backup mentioned [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/4241/how-to-create-a-system-image-in-windows-7/)?

Comment: Not sure why the downvote? Maybe it was a badly worded question. I've added more details and modified the question.

Comment: So if you can dual boot, you can use Norton Ghost (or similar tools) to get an image (i.e. backup) of windows and then create a new drive in mac book and put the image on that drive. There should be some problems with boot, so I encourage you to set that drive (on mac book) as logical.

Comment: Do you need a true Dualboot, or are you okay with using a Windows virtual machine in your Mac?

Comment: I need a true Dualboot. I'm doing development, which I find VMs are a bit clunky at times.

Comment: How good is the built-in windows restore program?

Comment: After researching, windows backup image cannot be restored to a bootcamp partition.

Comment: Convert your image file to a .wim format, then reburn your install cd replacing the original wim file on the dvd, have not tried this but may work. Or install windows clean and check that dual boot is working then use a different software to overwrite the partition with your custom image skipping the mbr part of the restore. I use Acronis but there are free oprions out there.

Answer (score 0):

Being a fan of VMs, I'd recommend you use a hypervisor on your Mac like Parallels or VMware Fusion. I've been using Fusion for a few years and have successfully used their migration tool. It's included in the product and will clone your Windows PC into a VM with relative ease.

- Here's how VMware describes it: https://www.vmware.com/support/windows_to_mac
- Here's how Parallels describes it: http://kb.parallels.com/en/115007

Comment: I need a strong DEV box. VMs have their quirks and frankly for testing their fine, but for actual DEV work I've had them have odd things happen.